# Bootstrap Modal appear only when there is an AJAX response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-modal

I want to make my Bootstrap Modal appear only when there is an AJAX response. Otherwise, I want this Bootstrap Modal to be hidden.

I have done the below. However, it does not work properly. The Modal keeps showing even if there is no response.

JavaScript:

```
<script>
//$(dialog).close();
$(".dialog").parent().hide();
// execute alerts ajax function every 1 second
setInterval(alerts, 10000);

function alerts(){// define alerts function
  $.ajax({    //create an ajax request to alerts.php
    type: "GET",
    url: "alerts.php",
    dataType: "html",   //expect html to be returned
    success: function(response){
          $("#myModal").modal();
          $("#modalbodyscreen").html(response);
          $.playSound('http://alixali.com/taxiapp/taxiappbeep');
    }
  });
}

// close and delete modals every 10 seconds
setTimeout(function(){
  //$(dialog).close();
  $(".dialog").parent().hide();
}, 10000);

</script>
```

alerts.php

```
<pre>
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
session_start();
$driver_id = $_SESSION['userId'];
include "header.php";
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM alerts WHERE driver_id = '$driver_id'");
$num = mysql_num_rows($result);
if ($num != 0) {
  while($data = mysql_fetch_row($result))
  {
      echo "<h5>Contact No:</h5><br>";
      echo $data[1]."<br>";
      echo "<h5>Address:</h5><br>";
      echo "https://www.google.com/maps/preview/@".$data[3].",".$data[2].",16z"."<br>";
      echo "<h5>Distance (km):</h5><br>";
      echo $data[5];
      $_SESSION['distance'] = $data[5];
  }
$delete_result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM alerts WHERE driver_id = '$driver_id'");
}
</pre>
```

Please advise and get me with your recommendations/solutions as soon as possible.

You can see this app on:
http://www.alixali.com/taxiapp/

Driver login:
username 1111
password 1111

Passenger login:
username ali
password 12345678

Regards,
Alixali

Comment: I guess `header.php` is producing output, which then is the `response` in ajax´ success-callback

Comment: did you try change $("#myModal").modal(); to $("#myModal").show();

Answer (score 0):

change `$("#myModal").modal();` to `$("#myModal").modal("show");`
and to hide the modals use `$(".myModals").modal("hide");`

here's a link to the bootstrap API documentation on [modals](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)

Comment: Thank you for the good advice and guidance. I am getting better results.

Answer (score 0):

try this 
`success: function(response){
          if(response != '')
         {
             $("#myModal").modal('show');
             $("#modalbodyscreen").html(response);
             $.playSound('http://alixali.com/taxiapp/taxiappbeep');`

```
     }
}`
```

Comment: Thank you for the good advice and guidance. I am getting better results.

Comment: dont forget to help other, and rate ur chosen solution @AlixaliApps